# Как перехватить ошибку в методе PHP?

Tags: php

В каком-то месте "падает" метод:

```
fwrite($fc, "[1]");
$arOrders = $obmen->runObmenOrdersIn();
fwrite($fc, [2]");
```

т.е., запись "1" есть, а "2" - уже нет.

Поставил в методе исключение в надежде найти место, где что-то не так и получить текст ошибки:

```
public function runObmenOrdersIn() {
        try{
            $allOrders['NEW'] = $this->getOrdersLast('NEW');
            $this->insertOrdersInDB($allOrders['NEW']);
            unset($allOrders['NEW']);
            $allOrders['CHANGED'] = $this->getOrdersLast('CHANGED');
            $this->updateOrdersInDB($allOrders['CHANGED']);
            unset($allOrders['CHANGED']);
            $allOrders['CANCELED'] = $this->getOrdersLast('CANCELED');
            $this->updateCanseledOrdersInDB($allOrders['CANCELED']);
            unset($allOrders['CANCELED']);
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Записываю, что возвращает метод:

```
$arOrders = $obmen->runObmenOrdersIn();
fwrite($fc, $arOrders);
```

Пусто.
Подскажите, как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: если пусто, то скорее всего в исключение он не заходит, поставить в конце ветки try - return 'исключение не произошло, чтобы убедиться'

Comment: Используйте отладку и пошагово пройдитесь по функции.

Comment: `fwrite($fc, [2]");` - а вы тут случаем кавычку не забыли?

Comment: может просто включить вывод ошибок? `error_reporting = e_all`, `ini_set.display_errors = true`

Comment: А как я их увижу? Это происходит на продакшене в момент обмена данными с 1С.

Answer (score 0):

Внутри метода через каждую строчку пишете что нибудь типа

```
fwrite($fc, $alert");
exit();
```

где **$alert**- просто строка с текстом и удаляйте это последовательно до тех пор пока не увидите что следующая строчка не выводиться, и вы поймете на какой строчке все "падает"

Comment: Мне важнее понять, что за ошибка.

Comment: ну как найдете строчку которая валит работу, сделайте var_dump('неработающая строчка'); узнаете что она возвращает, почитаете документацию, узнаете что должна возвращать, что должна принимать и все в том духе.. или идете в функцию которую вызываете это строкой, делаете там все тоже самое снова и так до тех пор пока не дойдете до причины.. подумаете, поковыряете и поймете в чем ошибка, так дебаг и работает))

тут же не телепаты что бы знать весь ваш код в методе и функция вызываемых методом поглядев на пару строк

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая ф-ия [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php) , с её помощью можно поймать все ошибки и краши.
Использовать примерно так:

```
register_shutdown_function( "callback" );
function callback()
{
    var_dump(error_get_last());
}

$a='string';
$a->a();
```